# Immediately lock screen when I close laptop lid under Gnome 3 (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

How can I configure my Ubuntu 14.04, logging in using Gnome 3, to lock the screen when I close my laptop lid?

All Settings ► Power only offers `Do nothing` or `Suspend` as options when I close the lid.

All Settings ► Brightness & Lock is configured with Lock *ON*, Lock screen after *Screen turns off*.  It doesn't seem to work.

I've tried editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to set `HandleLidSwitch=lock` and rebooting; nothing changed.

Comment: Having changed nothing, it's now working as expected.  *headdesk* Thank you for the suggestions, I hope they'll be of use to anyone searching for it later.

Answer (score 4):

Easy way: after changing

```
HandleLidSwitch=lock
```

you have to restart the service

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

Comment: This should be the top answer, simple and effective

Answer (score 3):

There may be other simple method available for what you want but you can  lock you screen using this script upon closing your lid. I found it on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts). I am trying to keep it short. For detail explanation you can visit the link.

- Make the environment variables available for root.

  `gedit ~/export_x_info`

  and paste the following contets

  ```
  # Export the dbus session address on startup so it can be used by any other environment
  sleep 5
  touch $HOME/.Xdbus
  chmod 600 $HOME/.Xdbus
  env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > $HOME/.Xdbus
  echo 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' >> $HOME/.Xdbus
  # Export XAUTHORITY value on startup so it can be used by cron
  env | grep XAUTHORITY >> $HOME/.Xdbus
  echo 'export XAUTHORITY' >> $HOME/.Xdbus
  ```
- Make it eecutable using

  `chmod 700 ~/export_x_info`
- You need to run it on startup. So add it to **Startup Applications**. Select **Startup Programs** from Gnome Menu, and click Add.

  ```
  Name:<Any name you want>
  Command:/home/your_user/export_x_info
  ```
- Now you need to edit your /etc/acpi/lid.sh file which catch lid open and close event. ***Change user_name with your user name***

  `gksudo gedit /etc/acpi/lid.sh` and  paste

  `/home/your_user/lid_event` just after `#!/bin/bash`. Save and close.
- Now you need to create a script for close event so that you can lock your screen.

  `gedit ~/lid_event` and paste the following.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  grep closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state  
   if [ $? = 0 ]
   then
   source /home/user_name/.Xdbus
   DISPLAY=:0.0 su user_name -c "gnome-screensaver-command -l"
   fi
  ```

  Also check for /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state file  because `LID0` may be `LID`.
- Now restart your ACPI using

  `sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart`
- Make sure that the Power Management option for laptop lid closed is set to do nothing

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in gnome-tweak-tool `Suspend when lid is closed` is `on` under power option

Then change `HandleLidSwitch=lock` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

after that run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` to restart service