# xUbuntu: use pm-suspend to suspend the computer

Tags: suspend, xfce, xfce4-power-manager

When I use the default way of xUbuntu to suspend the computer (close the lid for example), it fails, but if I use pm-suspend, it works. How can I force xUbuntu 16.04 to use pm-suspend to suspend the computer?

Thank you!

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events