# Laptop doesn't suspend properly on closing lid

Tags: suspend, power-management, lenovo

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Lenovo G50 and everything is going fine except that I can't close the lid of my laptop without needing to reboot afterwards. When I close the lid (or if I run `pm-suspend`), my laptop screen goes dark for a few seconds, then turns back on.

The problem is that when I try resuming it, my laptop basically turns into a potato... For some reason, the network manager (both wifi and ethernet) doesn't work whatsoever, the terminal becomes extremely slow and I can't run any command using `sudo` because it will hang there forever.

I've tried changing the `logind.conf` file, I've tried changing the `Power System Settings`, I've updated my Intel Graphics driver, I've installed tools like `pmi` or `laptop-mode`... I'm running out of ideas but I would do anything to fix this issue.

If there's any system information that could be useful, let me know and I'll add it to the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading around, I found that the issue was with the Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 WiFi card used in many Lenovo laptops (G50-80 in my case). Ubuntu doesn't seem to have the proper firmware for this card which makes it act up.

I also found out that turning off the Wifi before closing my laptop would prevent everything from bugging, so I put that and the solution from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events) together and created a file in `/etc/acpi/` to handle the lid closing event.

Add the following code using `sudo nano /etc/acpi/lid.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
  nmcli radio wifi off
  pm-suspend
else
  nmcli radio wifi on
fi
```

Next, add the following lines using `sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid`:

```
event=button/lid.*
action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

Now, uncomment and set the following line using `sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Finally, go into the `System Settings > Power` and put all closing lid options to `Do Nothing`.

Run the following to set the permissions and finalize the changes:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/acpi/lid.sh
sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
sudo service systemd-logind restart
```

Hopefully it works for you!

Comment: After trying everything across the internet to make my laptop sleep after lid close, this is the only solution for me on Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 12):

## **To change close lid action in Ubuntu :**

Open the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file in a text editor as root, for example,

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Change this line :

```
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

To this line :

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

**Make sure its commented out.**

Alternately you can also add this line, but i prefer the first one :

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

Then run :

```
sudo service systemd-logind restart
```

Or **reboot**.

## **To Troubleshoot the hibernate/suspend mode you should type following command in terminal :**

```
dmesg|less
```

There is usually an entry what application caused the suspension to fail:

```
[32467.560058] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.01 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[32467.560115] plasma-desktop D 0000000000000000 0 2065 1 0x00800004
```

## **Fix suspend on laptops**

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp
```

Now test suspend with :

```
sudo s2ram
```

If it doesn't work use :

```
sudo s2ram --force
```

Next edit this file :

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-suspend-linux
```

Change code to :

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/s2ram --force
```

**Edit :
Another fix :**

Put a script in ' /etc/pm/sleep.d/ ' , scripts there will be run at suspend and resume. The file name should start with an ordering number, 00-49 for user scripts (for more details, see man pm-suspend).

The script could look like this

```
#!/bin/sh
(killall -9 mount.nfs; exit 0)
```

If you're having problems, check /var/log/pm-suspend.log that will log the attempt to suspend and to run your script.

## **Ubuntu Suspend not working FIX**

Step 1:
Open up a terminal and create a script file as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd
```

Step 2:
Copy the entire script below into the file you just created and save it:

```
#!/bin/sh
 VERSION=1.1
DEV_LIST=/tmp/usb-dev-list
DRIVERS_DIR=/sys/bus/pci/drivers
DRIVERS="ehci xhci" # ehci_hcd, xhci_hcd
HEX="[[:xdigit:]]"
MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=2
BIND_WAIT=0.1
 unbindDev() {
  echo -n > $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
   for driver in $DRIVERS; do
    DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
    for dev in `ls $DDIR 2>/dev/null | egrep "^$HEX+:$HEX+:$HEX"`; do
      echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/unbind
      echo "$driver $dev" >> $DEV_LIST
    done
   #for bus in $EHCI_BUSES; do
     echo -n $bus > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
 # done
   done
 }
 bindDev() {
  if [ -s $DEV_LIST ]; then
    while read driver dev; do
      DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
      #for bus in $EHCI_BUSES; do
          echo -n $bus > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/bind
      #done
      while [ $((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS)) -gt 0 ]; do
          echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/bind
          if [ ! -L "$DDIR/$dev" ]; then
            sleep $BIND_WAIT
          else
            break
          fi
          MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=$((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS-1))
      done
     done < $DEV_LIST
  fi
  rm $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
   chvt 1
  chvt 7
}
 EHCI_BUSES="0000:00:1a.0 0000:00:1d.0"
case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
 unbindDev;;
     resume|thaw)
 bindDev;;
 esac
```

Step 3:
Give the script run permissions by typing:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd
```

Comment: I've tried every combination of those 2 but it still completely bugs out trying to suspend

Comment: What you mean with bugs out ? What happen when you suspend manually ?

Comment: If I try to suspend by any method, the network manager stops working, the terminal becomes extremely slow and I can't run any commands using `sudo` because it will hang indefinitely. I pretty much have no choice but to hard reboot my laptop (the command `reboot` makes the laptop hang on the shutdown screen)

Comment: Use the trouble shoot method i descibed in my answer to check wich program cause your ubuntu to freeze/bug.

Comment: Which line should I be looking for with `dmesg|less` ? It's endlessly long

Comment: The one that says "1 tasks refusing to freeze" and the most recent offcourse so first try to suspend, then check the log.

Comment: I tested out a few things, the output of closing the lid is here https://justpaste.it/1hjs2. It says that 11 tasks refused to freeze. I also tried using uswsup, but it would not work either unfortunately.

Comment: I have added another edit with a fix you could try. So after trying this all your ubuntu still freezes/ slows when u suspend ? Even manually or from command line ?

Comment: I don't know why but `sudo pm-suspend` started working out of nowhere (I think it was after installing uswsusp), but closing the lid still wouldn't suspend and would make my laptop crash. I ended up creating a file in `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` to handle closing lid events. I'll post an answer about what I did but thank you so much for your help <3 <3

Comment: No problem, glad its fixed.