# Disable standby on close of laptop only if ethernet it plugged in

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management

I know you can [disable standby when you close your laptop lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid), but is it possible to not have it go on standby if ethernet is plugged in?

So basically, whether on battery power or not I need it to work like this:

```
If laptop shell closed
    If ethernet not plugged in
        Go to standby
    Else
        Don't go to standby, ever
```

Is there a way to acheive this?

Comment: Try executing a script when the lid is closed and implement what you want in the script https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events

Comment: Yes thus can be done. Hopefully someone posts an answer today.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with some info from other answers, you can try this untested method:

From [Catch lid close and open events](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events)

- The script you want to call when the lid opens or closes has to be stored
  in `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`.
- Then there has to be created the correct file `/etc/acpi/events/lm_lid` with the content as follows:

  ```
  event=button/lid.*
  action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh
  ```
- Reboot your system to let this take effect. Or maybe it is enough to restart your ACPI using

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
  ```

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252002/help-testing-special-file-in-sys-class-net and [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)
the `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` script will look like this (change yournetworkcardname for your name of your network card. Use `ifconfig` to find it). You can choose between suspend or hibernate.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(head -c1 /sys/class/net/yournetworkcardname/carrier)" -eq 0 ]; then
    systemctl suspend
fi
```

Test the script with `bash -x /etc/acpi/lid.sh` and make sure it works. You might have to add the following to run the script as sudo without being prompted with a password, from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt:

```
myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

Maybe you will also have to call the script in the action with sudo.

Comment: This is much more elegant than what I had written so far.  It doesn't seem to be working though.  I'm not exactly sure where to look to debug this.  I wonder if it has anything to do with requiring authentication.  When I run `systemctl suspend` from a shell it says `Authentication is required to set a wall message` `Authenticating as myusername` followed by a password prompt.  I have to do this for both `==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.login1.set-wall-message ===` and `==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.login1.suspend ===` to get it to suspend.

Comment: @JoshI I have edited the answer with some ideas that I hope will help you debugging your problem.