# Is it possible to tell the computer press button when I close the lid?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, lock-screen, lid, gnome-screensaver

when I close the lid, the computer suspend and lock the screen.
If I changed the keyboard layout before I locked it, I can't change it back and unlock the screen.

When I press the shortcut for lock screen, it shows me different lock screen, in this lock screen I can change the keyboard layout.

I want that when I close the lid, the computer will press automatically on the lock screen shortcut, so I won't have to check the keyboard layout before I lock the screen. is that possible?

Edit:
I found that I need to write a script that indicates when the lid close and when it does- simulate super + L keys press.
The problem is that I don't know how to write this kind of script. I found the link below which has the "OnLidClose" event, but I dont know exactly how to use it. I put the code at the link in /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid and I tried to put the "OdLidClose" code in /etc/acpi/lid.sh, but it copied "$?" as "0".

link: [Catch lid close and open events](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events)

Comment: Possible via custom script. The lid suspend will have to be disabled and all the actions in sequence will have to be done by the script itself.

Comment: thanks for replying. I thought it would be something like this.
I currently found some information about acpi, but I don't know to write this kind of code..
I only managed to create the file lid.sh

Comment: Someone should write one and post. I would do that but somewhat busy lately. And yes, acpi is the way to go.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but can you help me please when you have time? I tried to write some scripts but it didn't work.. @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Comment: I will try to come up with something. Probably try to post it by Monday. Are you using just stock Ubuntu with GNOME desktop ?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 19.04 with Gnome. Thanks a lot! @SergiyKolodyazhnyy