# Laptop lid close doesn't suspend then the battery dies

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown, lid

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I followed the steps in the given link to send my laptop to sleep on closing the lid.

[Immediately lock screen when I close laptop lid under Gnome 3 (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521394/immediately-lock-screen-when-i-close-laptop-lid-under-gnome-3-14-04)

It worked. But after few hours, when I opened the lid again, I saw that the laptop shutdown because of no battery at all. Although, it was 100% charged before the closing the lid. Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Those instructions appear to be a "how to keep laptop running when closing lid and only lock the screen".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Oh! Thank You. I didn't see properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the link you followed to **lock the screen on lid close** you need to follow these steps to have a regular `suspend` when the lid is closed.

---

### Set Ubuntu Power Settings

From the Launcher select the cog for `System Settings`. Click the icon `Power` and this screen appears:

[image: Power Suspend]

Look at the line `When lid is closed` and set the options as they appear above to `Suspend`.

Close the window.

---

### Set systemd logind.conf settings

Invoke the `Terminal` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Edit the systemd logind.conf file by typing:

```
gksu gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Look for these two lines and change them to look like this:

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

You might have to change `ignore` or `lock` to read `suspend`. You might have to remove a leading `#`.

Save the file and quit `gedit`. After ensuring no applications (like word processor, spreadsheet, etc.) have files open type into the terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

Voila! everything is reversed and your system will operate as you expect.

Comment: That was beautifully explained. +1 from me.

Comment: no lid close option in settings on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

The link says that it is for locking the laptop on closing the lid. Therefore you locked the computer, got a blank screen and assumed it was sleeping. But, it was locked and still consuming power. If you want to send your laptop to sleep on closing the lid, then revert all your changes and follow the steps mentioned here:-

- Go to `System Settings` and choose `Power`.
- There, you will have the option of suspending the laptop on closing the lid when `On battery` and when `When plugged in`.
- Choose `Suspend` for both of them.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you help me in reverting the things? I am new to  ubuntu.

Comment: For that, I'll exactly have to know what you did. Did you follow the 1st answer completely in the link?

Comment: Which answer did you follow, I'll answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes I followed the first answer completely

Comment: In the mean time click the cog in the top right corner and select 'suspend' before closing the lid. This will put your computer to sleep instead of the lid close lock can take place.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes. Good Idea. I'll do that.

Comment: @Siddhant. Your welcome. I see you are new to ask ubuntu--welcome aboard. When you see helpful comments check the up arrow to let others know. I'll answer your question in 2 hours if the other fellow doesn't.

Comment: @Siddhant the answer you requested to reverse screen lock on lid close has been posted below.